# Error When Saving as Binary in ExtendScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save a script as binary in extendscript so a client cannot view our code but I am running into an issue. Hopefully someone here knows a workaround.

In my script I have it calling to include an outside data file to pull informational values the script needs;

```
#include "/Users/GratefullyDyed/Sublimation/data.js";
```

Now I need to change that file path to the path that will be on my clients computer. When I do that and try to save as binary I get an error that "file path does not exist", because the file path is on their computer and not mine.

Is there a simple way around this I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't save the source code in binary format, but you can apply base64 or any other encryption to store only the data

Comment: *"I need to change that file path to the path that will be on my clients computer."* It might be worth providing some more context since many might not be familiar with ExtendScript. This looks like a build directive, and usually build scripts are run offline before the code is shipped to the client. There is a lot of missing information here.